# Software recommendation for a MASM compiler

Tags: software-recommendation, compiling, compiler, assembler

I have been looking for a [MASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler) compiler for Ubuntu. I have moved all of my development tools to Ubuntu. Now I'm taking a MASM class, and I need a MASM compiler very badly. I have seen some [videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W72oRn1-zKc). They mostly use a DOS emulator, and they install MASM compiler in there. I'm not really for looking something like this.

Here is what I am looking for:

- Ideally it will have some logs to troubleshoot my programs.
- Graphic user interface is a plus, but I don't need it.
- I would prefer that the compiler is not an emulation of Windows (it would not need to use WineHQ).

I'm currently using Sublime Text with a MASM package so I don't need an IDE, however if the solution that you have is an IDE that would be OK, like a lightweight alternative to Visual Studio maybe.

What would be a good MASM Compiler under these circumstances?

Comment: I'm sorry about asking such a broad question. I will change it.

Comment: well I got lucky when searching for it ;) the jwasm google code page made it an easy search and answer :D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest jwasm (on [sourcforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwasm/) and on [google code](https://code.google.com/p/winasm-studio/wiki/JWASM))

The google page lists a lot of alternatives and also shows why jwasm is better than these. Nelow a direct copy from the google code page so you get a good suggestion and you get alternative programs. You will need to try them to decide what works for you. JWasm works on Linux; all the others might not.

> **JWasm**

**Features**

- Free.
- native support for output formats Intel OMF, MS Coff (32- and 64-bit), Elf (32-and 64-bit), Bin and DOS MZ.
- precompiled JWasm binaries are available for DOS, Windows and Linux. For OS/2 and FreeBSD, makefiles are supplied.
- Instructions up to SSE4.2 are supported.
- JWasm is written in C. The source is portable and has successfully been tested with Open Watcom, MS VC, GCC and more.
- JWasm's source code is released under the Sybase Open Watcom Public License, which allows free commercial and non-commercial use.

> **Compared to other assemblers**

**MASM**

- JWasm is free, no artificial license restrictions, can be used to create binaries for any OS.
- JWasm is open source, forget the annoying MASM bugs ...
- More output formats supported (Bin, ELF).
- Optionally very small object modules can be created
- Better support for Open Watcom, for example the register-based calling convention
- JWasm is faster than Masm.

**TASM**

- JWasm is available. TASM isn't legally available. And LZASM, which is sort of a TASM clone, understands IDEAL mode only.
- JWasm has full support for STRUCTs and UNIONs. TASM has severe limitations and bugs in this area.
- JWasm supports virtually all MASM v6 features (PROTO, INVOKE, hll directives, ... ), most of which TASM won't understand.
- JWasm supports instructions up to SSE4, TASM is behind.

**POASM**

- JWasm is open source
- JWasm additionally supports output in OMF, ELF and binary format
- JWasm supports 16-bit and segmented memory models. POASM understands FLAT only.
- JWasm is compatible with MASM's implementation of macros. POASM isn't.
- POASM lacks the ability to create a listing file.

**WASM**

- JWasm's macro capabilities are ways better than Wasm's.
- JWasm fully supports Masm v6 syntax. In Wasm, most of the additions done in Masm v6 are missing.
- Besides OMF, JWasm supports COFF, ELF and binary output formats.
  JWasm supports 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is important to point out that jwasm lack support for POSIX based calling conventions (System V like systems), so, if you are willing to use fetures like proto/procs with parameters, be aware that those parameters will be passed throught the registers by C/C++ compilers, but jwasm wont use the right registers but the stack as parameters so you won't be able to use parameters names as usual on 64bits architecture.